# Packet CRC Computation Approach

Tags: c++, performance, crc

I am writing a class that is reading in incoming packets of serial data.  The packets are laid out with a header, some data, and are followed by a two byte CRC.

I also have written a class where I can build up packets to send.  This class has  GenerateCRC() method which allows the caller to compute a CRC for a packet which they have built up via calls to other methods.  The GenerateCRC() call is only meant to be called once the packet header and data have been set up properly.  As a result, this method iterates over the packet in a for loop and computes the CRC this way.

Now that I'm writing code to read in the packets, I need to verify them by computing a CRC.  I'm trying to reuse the previous "builder" class as much as possible given that as I'm reading in the packet, I want to store it in memory and the best way to do so is to use the "builder" class.  However, I have hit a snag with computation of the CRC.

There are two main approaches that I'm considering and I am having trouble weighing the pros and cons and deciding on an approach.  Here are my two choices:

1. Compute the CRC as I read in the bytes.  The data that I'm reading in is pushed onto a queue, so I pop off the bytes one at a time.  I would keep a running "total" CRC and be finished with the computation as soon as the last data byte is read in.
2. Compute the CRC only once I have read in the full packet.  In this case, I don't have to keep a running total, but I would have to iterate over the packet again.  I should note that this would allow me to reuse my previously written code.

Currently I am leaning towards option 1 and moving any common functionality between the "builder" and the "reader" to a separate header file.  However, I want to make sure that the first option is in fact the better one in terms of performance since it does make my code a bit more jumbled.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It seems to be a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pick Door #2.  That allows simpler validation of the code by using identical code on both ends, and also permits faster CRC algorithms to be used that process four or eight bytes at a time.